# LocationClient.getLastLocation() always returns null on Android 2.3.6

Tags: android, google-play-services, location-client

I'm using LocationClient as described in the official documentation.
Everything works fine on Android 4.1+

However, on an Android 2.3.6 device, getLastLocation() systematically returns null, no matter when or how many times I call it.
I have already rebooted the device (this had made the same issue disappear on Android 4.1).

The service *is* available; onConnect() gets called; the app has proper permissions (this is obvious, otherwise it wouldn't work on 4.1 either); gps and wifi location are enabled in System Settings. Google Maps and other location-aware apps work fine. I do have Google Play Store installed.

What else can be wrong?

I've noticed that the installed version of Google Play Services is 5.something, while the latest is 6.1. Is it normal? It is supposed to stay updated automatically, and indeed it usually does, as this version is dated july2014 and the device is much older. I guess this is the latest version for 2.3.6?

Comment: Do you actually start listening for location updates via a `LocationRequest` in your app?

Comment: No, I don't. According to http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html that shouldn't be necessary. It could be expected that the very first time you call getLastLocation() you could get null, but as soon as a location is available, it should automatically and transparently stored and you should be able to get it with getLastLocation(). It is supposed to avoid the complication of listening for updates unless you actually need to be informed every time the location is updated.

Comment: However, after a few hours, it started working, so it doesn't seem to be a matter of Android version but just some general bug. Maybe the same I experienced with 4.1, only that in that case (perhaps just by chance) a reboot was enough.

Comment: Does start listening via LocationRequest actually make a difference? It is not supposed to. If everything worked as documented, the only difference would be that you would be notified when the location is available, but it shouldn't make it be available sooner. Merely connecting LocationClient should by itself make the location become available as soon as possible. But it wouldn't surprise me if things didn't work as documented: they rarely do. Is this the case in your experience?